# Rails: parameters visible in console but not accessible as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am sending a get request to the url: `groups/:id.json`

In my rails server console I see the following:

```
Processing by GroupsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
```

But I have no access to the params object in this show controller method. The following:

```
puts "puts params!"
puts params
```

Puts nothing to the console:

```
puts params!
#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f7f9c482bf0>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f7f9c482bf0>):
```

My rails project is serving as an API for an angular ui-router frontend and I am using Devise for user management. What could be preventing my params from showing up in this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling `id` as a method on params? It probably should be `params[:id]` instead of `params.id`

Answer (score 1):

It's the way you are trying to access `paramters` in your controller action. It should be `params[:id]`. [Take a look at the docs, 'Parameters' section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).